# What is the small barrel type connector called?

Tags: connector, identification, cables

I just ordered a barrel connector but it's bigger then the one i need, What is the small barrel type connector called. My original one has a yellow ring around it, Is that an indicator of what type it is?

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem buying tyres for my 1st car. I was totally surprised to find that there is a whole load of different tyre sizes ;)

Comment: -1 for the crappy picture.  You should have been able to see for yourself that everything except the critical part you are trying to show is in focus.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, if it was more clear were you going to try to estimate the diameter from the picture? It's a crap picture but it's good enough to understand what s/he's talking about.

Comment: @TheP: That's not the point.  The issue is the *"Eh, who cares"* or *"These peons are here to serve me, so they'll take any slop I chose to throw at them"* attitude.  Neatness, clarity, and respect for those you are presenting to matter A LOT.  Merely technically sufficient is not good enough.

Comment: I did try a few photos but none of them focused on the end of the connector properly so i gave up, Was hoping people could see roughly what it was.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, So you respond with the attitude that "these peons must bow and scrape before me if they want me to answer their question"?

Comment: @TheP: No, but they do have to show simple respect by providing a clear presentation of the question.  This is really not hard, with no bowing and scraping envolved.  (Of course you knew that, which is why you had to extrapolate my argument to absurdity to make your point).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the small barrel type connector called.

It's called a barrel connector with a different diameter.

Typically I see these connectors specified in 0.1 mm increments.

> My original one has a yellow ring around it, Is that an indicator of what type it is?

Within one particular vendor's product line, it may be. But you might find a compatible connector from another vendor with a different color.

Comment: Thanks, think im going to have to giveup looking on the internet and goto a shop and match it up.

Answer (score 4):

It's still a barrel plug. Whip out your calipers to verify, but I'd say that's a 4.0mm/0.7mm barrel plug.

Comment: Is 4.0mm the outside of the connector and 0.7mm the inner hole?

Comment: @Exoon: Correct. But verify yourself with the actual plug of course.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly you hit one of those nasty secrets of electronics: lack of standardization!

Power jacks are built in a wild, crazy (and admittedly quite stupid) variety of sizes. Behold the horror of any designer (and any user) in this Wikipedia page on [coaxial power connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector)!

Excerpts (emphasis mine):

> A coaxial power connector is an electrical power connector used for
>   attaching extra-low voltage devices such as consumer electronics to
>   external electricity. Also known as barrel connectors, concentric
>   barrel connectors or tip connectors, these small cylindrical
>   connectors come in an **enormous variety of sizes**.
>
> Contact ratings commonly vary from **unspecified** up to 5 amp (11 amps
>   for special hi-power versions). Voltage is again often **unspecified**, up
>   to 48 V with 12 V typical. The smaller types usually have lower
>   ratings, both for current and voltage.
>
> It is quite possible that **new sizes will continue to appear and
>   disappear**. One possible reason that a particular manufacturer may use
>   a new size is to discourage use of third-party power supplies, either
>   for technical reasons or to promote use of their own products, or
>   both.
>
> **The sizes and shapes of connectors do not consistently correspond to
>   the same power specifications across manufacturers and models**. Two
>   connectors from different manufacturers with different sizes could
>   potentially be attached to power supplies with the same voltage and
>   current. Alternatively, connectors of the same size can be part of
>   power supplies with different voltages and currents. **Use of the wrong
>   power supply may cause severe equipment damage, or even fire.**

I would describe the situation as "wild monkeys gone berserk".

Good Luck!